# How to make a log-in and each user has their own unique profile on C# with MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, authentication

I have two Window forms: one for log-in, and one for the profile of the user.

My goal is each user has their own unique profiles, like accounts on social media.

How can I make the user's log-in correspond to their unique details (full name, age, etc.) on the second form?

I could only code for the log-in of the user, but the rest I could not do anymore. The following is the log-in that I have made:

```
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
DB db = new DB();
String username = textboxUsername.Text;
String password = textboxPass.Text;

DataTable table = new DataTable();

MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `adminUsername` = @usn and `adminPassword`= @pass", db.getConnection());

command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;

adapter.SelectCommand = command;

adapter.Fill(table);

//if user exists or not
if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    adminHomePage homepage = new adminHomePage();
    homepage.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else
{   // check if the username field is empty
    if (username.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Your Username To Login", "Empty Username", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }// check if the password field is empty
    else if (password.Trim().Equals(""))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Your Password To Login", "Empty Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    // check if the username or the password don't exist
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username Or Password", "Wrong Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
}
```